# require.js doesn't see required module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Well, yes, I'm sorry for this question, it was repeated many times and I found lots of solutions but they don't help. Maybe, I am doing something wrong from the very beginning.
I load require.js in index.html like that. It works fine.

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

In main.js I load jQuery and my module.js

```
require(['jquery', 'module'], function ($, module) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('yohoho');    
        module.foo();
    }); 
});
```

In module.js I have

```
define('module', [], function () {
    var module = {
        foo: function () {
            alert('foo');
        },
        bar: function () {
            alert('bar');
        }
    };
    return  module;
});
```

So, jQuery loads fine and works (alerts 'yohoho'). Module doesn't work. Variable module, passed as argument, is defined and has fields like id, url, etc., but no foo or bar. Error is "module.foo is not a function"
P.S. solutions like "change name to ./module", or "return object without function", or "use foo outside document.ready" don't help.
UPD This code does work
main.js

```
require(['one', 'two', 'three'], function (one, two, three) {
    one.foo();
    two.foo();
    three.foo();
});
```

one.js

```
define('one', [], function () {
    return {
        foo: function () {
            alert('one foo');
        }
    }
})
```

two.js and three.js have same code with different module names.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed file module.js to xmodule.js and all references to 'xmodule' and it works fine now.